# How to remove "allowmethods:error" entry in apache error_log

Tags: apache, varnish, mod-pagespeed

I have only allowed GET, POST methods in my apache server. It shows lot of times error like below which is of no use to me. How can I block these errors to come in apache error log

```
[Mon Aug 22 18:43:27.232168 2016] [allowmethods:error] [pid 19314:tid 139797637039872] [demowebsite.com] [client 224.0.0.0:80] AH01623: client method denied by server configuration: 'PURGE' to /var/www/demowebsite/
```

I also want to know what is causing it. I am using apache 2.4 + php 5.5 + mod_pagespeed + varnish.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using Apache 2.4.X

Just by setting:

```
LogLevel allowmethods:crit
```

you will be rising the level necessary to log to error log to critical level in that module so they won't show up for errors.